# Can the URL that a WCF service generates in jsdebug be changed?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF service that will be talking to a proxy, which will be talking to the user's browser.  The Proxy needs to talk to the service over http, and the browser needs to talk to the proxy using https.  The problem I am running into is that the WCF service is generating the servicePath with http, so when the user's browser talks to the proxy, it is also using http.  Is there any way i can override the servicePath that gets created in the /jsdebug and other javascript that the WCF service generates?

To summarize, i want the service to be accessed by http, but to serve its javascript with a URL of https

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought here:

If you are hosting you service in IIS, could you not just enable both the HTTP and HTTPS bindings. You can then create a service reference for your application and generate the proxy over HTTP, and create a script reference in your site that points to HTTPS.

Better still for your site, try always to use what is called a 'protocol-relative' url using `src='//myservice.domain.com?js` instead of `src='https://myservice.domain.com?js`.

This ensures that the script references on your site will follow the protocol currently used in the address bar of the browser. Paul Irish has a nice [article](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) on it...

Let us know if these helped u.

Gr,

Wouter